# 1 cluster with 3 nodes Elastic server concept

Tags: web, elasticsearch

When someone says my elasticserver is 1 cluster 3 node, what does it means ?
Does it means they have one cluster/machine behaving as a master and 3 saperate machine they called it node, or the concept is something different from my understanding?

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: The 3 nodes can be three different machines, 3 Amazon instances or 3 virtual machines. Also, they can be on the same physical machine. And "cluster" = bunch of nodes. So, most probably, they meant they have an Elasticsearch cluster made of three nodes.

Comment: @AndreiStefan and by nodes you mean it can be different machine or on the same physical machine, right?

Comment: A node is an Elasticsearch instance. Multiple instances/nodes can be started from the same machine and multiple nodes run just fine from the same machine.